# How to set-up Paas with asp.net on windows server

Tags: asp.net, paas

I have a windows server 2008 machine with static IP, I want to  make it available on cloud to other users/developers,

How to set-up [Paas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_as_a_service) with asp.net on windows server?

e.g.
http://www.appfog.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out Cloudify at http://www.gigaspaces.com/cloudify

You can use our windows integration (see the ec2-win cloud sample) to start a cloud machine running IIS. All you need is a 'recipe' which includes your .Net binaries (or links to them) and a few lines of code to install the Asp.Net app.

Barak

http://www.cloudifysource.org/